# 2 divs position

Tags: css, html, position

Again me with my divs =(.
I have this:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="body">
  <div id="..."></div>
  <div id="..."></div>

  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

and css:

```
#body { width: 100%; margin 0 auto; }
#content {   position: absolute;   height: 200px; width: 100%; }
#footer {   height: 63px;   clear:both; }
```

Now result:
content div with much text and footer under text.

How can I make my footer under all content-area?

Comment: Side note: an auto margin is useless if the width is 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered this situation several times.  I've been using [sticky footers](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).  It's widely compatible with several browsers and just seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this styling you will see the (blue) #footer under the (red) #content as you requested:

```
#body {width: 600px; margin 0 auto; }
#content {position: relative; height: 200px; width: 600px; background-color: red; }
#footer {height: 63px; clear:both; width: 600px; background-color: blue; }
```

Comment: Ahh sorry. It was a typo. The position on #content should not be absolute, but relative.

Comment: My content-div should be over another divs from body. So I can't change it position to relative.

Comment: Hmm... The #content is under the #body. This means that the content-div is placed inside of the body-div, right?

So the body-div is actually just seen as a "container" containing the content-div and others if you like this.

So the content-div can be placed on top of the body-div if you like that.